# Android is there a custom widget or easy way to enter email or phone information into activity screen?

Tags: android

I need a super easy to use way for my users to enter phone and email information. Is there a sample of a good way to do this? I think many apps would benefit, regular EditText is way to cumbersome for user to enter such common information. Its partly validation but partly just providing a super easy way to enter this information.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Androider... The following xml will launch the appropriate soft keyboard for phones and email.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/EditTextSMSPhoneNumber" 
android:text="@string/edit_text_sms_phone_number" 
android:inputType= "phone"
android:hint= "@string/edit_text_sms_phone_number_hint"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</EditText>

android:inputType= "textEmailAddress"
```

This may or not be helpful to you.

JAL

Comment: where did you get edit_text_sms_phone_number?  what values are for this?

Comment: @androider... that is just a user defined hint from my string.xml as in <string name="edit_text_sms_phone_number_hint">Enter Phone Number (XXXABCYYYY)</string>